# knowing how many times a convolution kernel is used for each forward propagation in Keras

Tags: keras, convolution, keras-layer

Any way to know how many times a convolution kernel is used for one inference in Keras? Of course, this will be a 'high' number because the kernel is applied many times. Any way to know this given the `model`?

Comment: I don't think there is a function for that, but you can just compute it yourself knowing the kernel size, stride, padding and input size

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but isn't that just the height and width of the output shape of your convolutional layer (assuming 2d convolution)? So, if your conv2d output shape is `(batch_size, height, width, features)` it means that the kernel was applied `height*width` times, each time generating one new "pixel" with `features` channels.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have any rule of thumb for this,
You have to try applying kernel and see what fits your model.